# Chrome 77 remote device debug issue

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, frontend, web-frontend

Is any one facing issues with remote device debug on Chrome 77 on Mac. I am unable to debug android device on Chrome 77.

Comment: Yes - same issue here on my mac

Comment: Yes, it is a genuine issue, both on Windows and Mac

Answer (score 5):

A weird but functional solution without having to download an old version of chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/15368759?msgid=15847043

1. Download / Open Firefox
2. Navigate to about:debugging#/setup in Firefox
3. Disable USB Devices and Enable it again in Firefox
4. Go to Chrome chrome://inspect/#devices. You will now find your device(s) listed

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue regarding chrome version 77 in windows too.. Kindly download the previous version like 73 or 74.. 
https://www.neowin.net/news/google-chrome-730368386-offline-installer/